# Parsing XML file using php

Tags: php, xml, parsing, simplexml

Rephrase it. Here's my code together with the XML. Everytime I try to print_r the response, It does not reflect anything.

```
$portal   = 'CaregiverPortal';
$userName = 'dxt3uyk27U3wRRrzaFGiwQ==';
$password = 'wD81PILmPuJX2fyFek937A==';
$url      = "https://webapp.healthcaresynergy.com:8002/demoalpha/CaregiverPortalMobile/CaregiverPortalS   ervice.svc?singleWsdl";         
$option   = array('trace' => 1 ); 

$xml      = '<soapenv:Envelope   xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">'.
           '<soapenv:Header/>'.
           '<soapenv:Body>'.
              '<LoginCaregiverPortal>'.
                 '<userName>Anything</userName>'.
                 '<password>Anything</password>'.
                 '<portal>'.$portal.'</portal>'.
                 '<caregiverID>'.$userName.'</caregiverID>'.
                 '<timeStamp>'.$password.'</timeStamp>'.
              '</LoginCaregiverPortal>'.
           '</soapenv:Body>'.
         '</soapenv:Envelope>';

$client = new LocalSoapClient($url, $option, $xml);

try 
{ 
 $client->LoginCaregiverPortal();
 $response = $client->__getLastResponse(); 
 //echo 'result';
 //echo "<br/>";
 //echo htmlspecialchars($response);
 $xml = simplexml_load_string($response);
 $json = json_encode($xml);
 $array = json_decode($json,TRUE);
 print_r($array);
```

}

this is what I get as a result.

```
Array ( )
```

I think This is where I'm getting an empty result.

```
 $xml = simplexml_load_string($response);
 $json = json_encode($xml);
 $array = json_decode($json,TRUE);
 print_r($array);
```

Many thanks for the help.

Comment: Why are you trying to use JSON at all?

Comment: do a `var_dump($xml);` at the bottom - do you get anything? If so, please show it.

Comment: Please, remove the horrible "turn the SimpleXML object into JSON and then into an array" hack. SimpleXML has lots of useful accessors for dealing with XML; why waste all that to turn it into a much uglier array? It looks like you've checked what `$response` contains already. Show us that, and if the problem is below that point, we don't need to see where that data came from. Then perhaps try [these debug functions](https://github.com/IMSoP/simplexml_debug) to examine the `$xml` object, as `var_dump` can lie to you.

Comment: I'm willing to bet that your actual "problem" is that the XML contains namespaces (tags with colons in them); without seeing the content, I can't give a full example, but basically you need to use the [`->children()`](http://php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.children.php) and [`->attributes()`](http://php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.attributes.php) methods. And don't trust `var_dump`.

Answer (score 1):

While it is difficult to tell much, as you have not provided the code of `LocalSoapClient` that you have used in your program and there is not much known to me in terms of the requirements of healthcaresynergy.com.

However I see two probable errors. The two lines in your soap request should probably be:

```
'<userName>'.$userName.'</userName>'.
'<password>'.$password.'</password>'.
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all the answers guys. It really helped me a lot to understand it.

However, I came up with a solution on nmy one which can and may help others as well if ever they encounter issues as such.

**Here's what the try bracket in try catch was modified**

```
  try 
{ 
 $client->LoginCaregiverPortal();
 $response = $client->__getLastResponse(); 
 //echo 'result';
 //echo "<br/>";
 //echo htmlspecialchars($response);
 $p        = xml_parser_create();
          xml_parse_into_struct($p, $response, $vals, $index);
          xml_parser_free($p);
          echo "Index array\n";
          echo('<pre>');
          print_r($index);
          echo('<pre/>');
          echo "\nVals array\n";
          print_r($vals);
     }
```

Comment: Obviously, if you're happy with it, fine. But I would really advise you to learn how to use SimpleXML rather than struggle with that awful function. The format returned is more like a dump of the parser loop than actual usable data, so you end up having to re-parse it into something useful. If you just show us what's in `$response`, we can show you how to use SimpleXML, and it will make your life much easier.

Answer (score 0):

This JSON-encode-decode trick of turning the whole SimpleXML object into an array is entirely counter-productive, so firstly, drop that, and keep this bit:

```
 $client->LoginCaregiverPortal();
 $response = $client->__getLastResponse(); 
 $xml = simplexml_load_string($response);
```

What you now have in `$xml` is a [SimpleXMLElement object](http://php.net/manual/en/class.simplexmlelement.php). This has a lot of "magic" methods for letting you navigate through the XML, most of which are [demonstrated on this page of the PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/simplexml.examples-basic.php).

---

Since this is a SOAP response, my guess is that the problem you're having is with "XML namespaces" - a tag name with a colon in, like `<S:Envelope>` is actually a tag called `Envelope` in the namespace with the local prefix of `S`. In SimpleXML, you have to "select" namespaces with [`->children()`](http://php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.children.php) and [`->attributes()`](http://php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.attributes.php).

You haven't shown the structure of the XML you got back, but assuming [the sample in your other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24458454/looping-in-a-multidimensional-array-using-php) is the result of running `xml_parse_into_struct` over it, it must look, in part, something like this:

```
<S:Envelope>
    <S:Body>
        <LoginCareGiverPortalResponse>
            <LoginCareGiverPortalResult>
                <A:Agencies>
                    <B:KeyValueOfIntHealthAgencyD9J3W_PIR>
                        <B:Value>
                        </B:Value>
                    </B:KeyValueOfIntHealthAgencyD9J3W_PIR>
                </A:Agencies>
                <A:Token>vy8BMS8nDIFdQWRTb6wyNDGGUMgBzHtOXU6mHqZgdxhRAbi0qkwluK9pjt03OQyf</A:Token>
            </LoginCareGiverPortalResult>
        </LoginCareGiverPortalResponse>
    </S:Body>
</S:Envelope>
```

To get the value of the `A:Token` tag (as mentioned on your other question), you would write this:

```
$token_element = $xml->children('S', true) // select the 'S' namespace
    ->Body                // $xml already points to <S:Envelope>
        ->children(null)  // select the namespace with no prefix
            ->LoginCareGiverPortalResponse
                 ->LoginCareGiverPortalResult
                     ->children('A', true) // select the 'A' namespace
                          Token;
// $token_element is an object pointing at that tag, we want its text content:
$token_text = (string)$token_element;
```

---

One caveat, though: the prefixes 'A' and 'B' have no universal meaning, and there is no guarantee that they won't get switched around in a different response. At the top of the response, you'll see attributes like `xmlns:a="http://example.net/xml-namespaces/Thingummy" xmlns:b="http://example.net/xml-namespaces/Grommet"`; those are the actual namespace identifiers, which *won't* change. `xmlns:a` is for everything beginning `a:`, and so on; the one just saying `xmlns=` is the "default namespace", for tags with no prefix like `<LoginCareGiverPortalResponse>`.

So if you look up what `A`, `B`, and the default are in your current example, you could write this:

```
// Define our own short-hands for the different namespaces
define('NS_SOAP', 'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/'); // This is standard
define('NS_RESPONSE', 'http://example.net/xml-namespaces/OurResponses');
define('NS_THINGUMMY', 'http://example.net/xml-namespaces/Thingummy');
define('NS_GROMMET', 'http://example.net/xml-namespaces/Grommet');

// Use them instead of the prefixes when selecting our namespaces
$token_element = $xml->children(NS_SOAP) // select the 'S' namespace
    ->Body                // $xml already points to <S:Envelope>
        ->children(NS_RESPONSE)  // select the "main" namespace
            ->LoginCareGiverPortalResponse
                 ->LoginCareGiverPortalResult
                     ->children(NS_THINGUMMY) // select the 'A' namespace
                          Token;
```