# Looping in a multidimensional Array using PHP

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I'm having a hard time looping in a multidimensional array. I'm not an expert of some sort when it comes to PHP. What I want to happen is to search for a certain field. If it hits the right field, then it will grab the data and store in a variable and if it does not hit the right field, it will continue to search for the right field.

Here's the array

```
[111] => Array
    (
        [tag] => B:VALUE
        [type] => close
        [level] => 7
    )

[112] => Array
    (
        [tag] => B:KEYVALUEOFINTHEALTHAGENCYD9J3W_PIR
        [type] => close
        [level] => 6
    )

[113] => Array
    (
        [tag] => A:AGENCIES
        [type] => close
        [level] => 5
    )

[114] => Array
    (
        [tag] => A:TOKEN
        [type] => complete
        [level] => 5
        [value] => vy8BMS8nDIFdQWRTb6wyNDGGUMgBzHtOXU6mHqZgdxhRAbi0qkwluK9pjt03OQyf
    )

[115] => Array
    (
        [tag] => LOGINCAREGIVERPORTALRESULT
        [type] => close
        [level] => 4
    )

[116] => Array
    (
        [tag] => LOGINCAREGIVERPORTALRESPONSE
        [type] => close
        [level] => 3
    )

[117] => Array
    (
        [tag] => S:BODY
        [type] => close
        [level] => 2
    )

[118] => Array
    (
        [tag] => S:ENVELOPE
        [type] => close
        [level] => 1
    )
```

and here's my code and I would like to apologize first for not being able to complete it. :D ......i have totally no idea on what to place.....and searching is making me more confuse...sorry....

here's the code

```
$last = count($vals) - 1;
foreach ($vals as $i => $row) {
    if (!$vals == '114') {
        next
    }
    else {
        $sessiontoken = <------store the value here
    }
}
```

Comment: This is the response from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24455900/parsing-xml-file-using-php isn't it? I think I can see enough of the structure here to show you a much nicer way of working with it.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
foreach ($values as $key => $value){
    if ($key == '114') {
            if($value['tag']==='A:TOKEN')
               $sessiontoken = $value['value'];
    }
}
```

Comment: Given the indexes of the outer array, I'd say that the OP actually wants to know when `$key == '114'` and then store `$value['value']`.

Comment: @PatrickQ you right that  makes more sense I edited, now Im not sure which value he wanted to store

Comment: Actually I wanted to store `vy8BMS8nDIFdQWRTb6wyNDGGUMgBzHtOXU6mHqZgdxhRAbi0qkwluK9pjt03OQyf`

Comment: @user3771496 ok then replace with `$value['value']`

Comment: I wanted to check if TAG is equal to A:TOKEN and if it does then it will store `vy8BMS8nDIFdQWRTb6wyNDGGUMgBzHtOXU6mHqZgdxhRAbi0qkwluK9pjt03OQyf` it to $sessiontoken

Comment: @user3771496 I added one more condition, see my edit

Answer (score 0):

Your actual question suggests you are looking to always return key `'114'`. In that case, you don't need a loop at all, just reference that key:

```
$sessiontoken = $vals['114']['value'];
```

However, what I think you *actually* want is to find whichever element has a `'tag'` of `'A:TOKEN'`, which would look like this:

```
foreach ($vals as $i => $row) {
    // Here, $row is one item from the $vals array
    // You don't want to think about $vals in the condition, just $row
    if ( $row['tag'] != 'A:TOKEN' ) {
        continue; // there's no "next" keyword in PHP
    }
    else {
        $sessiontoken = $row['value'];
    }
}
```

I'd probably swap the if around like this, though:

```
foreach ($vals as $i => $row) {
    if ( $row['tag'] == 'A:TOKEN' ) { // Positive tests are easier to read
        $sessiontoken = $row['value'];
    }
    // you can look for other tags at the same time with elseif ( ... )
    else {
         continue; // only if none of your conditions are met
    }
    // if there's nothing after the end of the else, 
    //  you don't need the continue at all
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Assuming you want to find the the session token which is contained in only one of your results. Do the following:

```
foreach ($vals as $i => $array_value){
    if (isset($array_value[$i]['value']) {
        $sessiontoken = $array_value[$i]['value'];
        break; // stop looping after it is found
    }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't quite make sense. What it does is look for entries like `$vals[0][0]['value']`, `$vals[1][1]['value']`, and so on, because of the way you're reusing `$i`.

Answer (score -1):

This one liner right here should be fixed:

```
if (!$vals == '114') {
```

Assuming that you want to store the session if you found the item you want at position 114, you should do something like this. I'm under the assumption that you have an array at position 114, and then you have keys that are pointing to a value? It seems like from your description that each key is actually an array that points to a value? Assuming that it's a regular key-value pair, here's something you can try:

```
foreach ($vals as $key=>$value)
{
    if ($key !== '114')
    {
        continue;
    } else {
        // check if value exists
        if (!empty($value['value'])
        {    
             $sessionToken = $value['value'];  
        }
    }
}
```

If it's not a key-value pair, then you need to adjust it to something like:

```
foreach ($vals as $key=>$value)
{
    if ($key !== '114')
    {
        continue;
    } else {
        foreach ($value as $keyArray => $val) 
        {
           if ($keyArray == 'value')
            {    
                 $sessionToken = $value['value'];  
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `$value[value]` should be `$value['value']`, and I can't think in what situation the second version would work differently from the first. Not to mention that the whole thing can be reduced to `$sessiontoken = $vals['114']['value'];`

Comment: Oops. That should've been 'value', thanks for correcting. Well, the second one would work when $value['value'] isn't a key-value pair, as explained above. From the code, it seemed like '114' was pointing to an array of arrays. Therefore, if key == '114', and the value is actually an array of arrays, the OP would have to iterate through the array to find the value.

Comment: But the only thing you're testing in that loop is the key, so it comes to exactly the same thing. What the value is makes no difference, if you're searching for a key, `[$wanted_key]` is all you need.